# Kindo Grid in MVC is displaying raw data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm new to Kendo and learning how to integrate it with MVC and display data in a grid.

My controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult StudentList([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    DataSourceResult result = 
    _acc.GetStudent(StudId).ToDataSourceResult(request,
        model => new StudentModel
        {
            ID = model.ID,
            StudId = model.StudId,
            Name= model.Name,
            Email= model.FullName,
            custEmail = model.Email
        });


        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My view

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.StudentModel>()
                .Name("grid")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(c => c.StudId);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Email);
                })
                     .Pageable()
                     .Sortable()
                     .Filterable()
                     .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(550))
                     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                     .Ajax()
                     .Read(read => read.Action("StudList", "Student"))
                     .ServerOperation(false)
  )
)
```

And the out put I am getting in my browser looks like

`{"Data":[{"ID":1102,"StudId":4006,"Name":"Adam Lyon","Email":"alyon@regionofwaterloo.ca",",....,`

Does anyone has any idea why the data is not formatted in a grid form?

Comment: Are you getting a console error? Your code is missing the closing paren ) for `DataSource(...`

Comment: DataSource is already closed, it is down there, No error, all the data is coming but incorrect format, I want it in a Grid, but see above the output I have

Answer (score 1):

You will get that behavior if you link directly to the EmployeeList action - that should only be called by the grid. If your view name is say `Index`, you will need another action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Then in code link to that:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Employee List", "Index", "Employee")
```

Now the view will load and the Kendo grid will render and then call your EmployeeList action to populate the grid.

See the Kendo sample controller [here](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid). It has an action to load the view with the grid, and then CRUD actions the grid will call via AJAX.

Comment: Sorry, where should I include the line of code `@Html.ActionLink("Employee List", "Index", "Employee")`?

Comment: Please, any help how we can get this working. I have created a separate Index view and included the above action. Now it is getting `500 - Internal server error.`

Comment: You can call the index controller action from your menu (_Layout), a link on your homepage, etc. If you are getting a 500 error (server error), it would most likely be within your read action. So set a debug point and see if you are hitting it. Also, the action link I gave is just an example. Your actual link would depend on your controller name. In this example, the controller would be "EmployeeController". Use the syntax @Html.ActionLink("Label","ActionName","ControllerName").